# How to assign a weight to a term query in Lucene/Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am programatically constructing a BoostedQuery and I am creating two TermQuery instances which will be added to BoostedQuery instance:

```
Query query1 = new TermQuery(new Term("body", "new"));
Query query2 = new TermQuery(new Term("body", "york"));
```

But I am wondering if I could add some weight to this like I can do in qf field in Solr. Here is an example:

```
body:new^0.1
body:york^0.1
```

Any help or a pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Query.setBoost](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html#setBoost%28float%29)

```
query1.setBoost(0.1);
```

Or in a parsed query, using StandardQueryParser, precisely as you specified in your question:

```
body:new^0.1
```

See also, [Lucene scoring basics](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html#scoringBasics)

Comment: is it possible to add different weights to query terms? such as new=0.1 and york=0.5? how can I do this?

Comment: can you help me with this question? tnx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34783819/assigning-different-weights-to-different-query-terms-in-lucene

Comment: @KillBill - When you set the boost on `query1`, it doesn't affect `query2`.  You can set each subquery to have whatever boost you want.  Setting every subquery to the have same boost would actually be fairly pointless.

Comment: i want to give different weights to each term in the query? as i've mentioned in my question

Comment: @KillBill - Right, so give each `TermQuery` a different boost.  If you are using the `QueryParser`, the syntax supports this easily as well, see [the documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Boosting_a_Term)

Comment: if i set a negative score like, body:new^-0.1, throws an Lexical error saying,  Encountered: "-" (45), after : "".  do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @KillBill -  That's not supported by the `QueryParser`.  You can set a negative boost with the `Query.setBoost` method.