# Boosting search results for numbers in solr

Tags: solr

Suppose I have two documents with just one field as follows:

```
Document 1: foo bar 1
Document 2: foo baz 2
```

And a user searches for "foo baz 1"

Doucment 1 matches "foo" and "1" and Document 2 matches "baz" and "foo" so they would ordinarily be tied.  Is there any way to weight a match on a number higher than a match on text that would cause Document 1's match to be preferred over Document 2?

I don't want to boost by the number that matched, I want all numbers to be boosted by the same amount.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about boosting numbers in a query.

At query time you can [boosting a term](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser#TheStandardQueryParser-BoostingaTermwith%5E) or you could use payloads at index time: [Adding Boost to Score According to Payload of Multivalued Field at Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177913/adding-boost-to-score-according-to-payload-of-multivalued-field-at-solr)