# assigning different weights to different query terms in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I'm very new to lucene and wants to do the following. Suppose my query is,

> query = "apple growers fruit ipad mac"

,but I want to give different weights to these query terms like,

> query = "apple (0.2) growers (0.7) fruit (0.9) ipad (0.05) mac (0.06)

, the intuition is that i want to rank the documents that talks about apple in the sense of agriculture higher than those of which about tech.

I have seen here ([How to assign a weight to a term query in Lucene/Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570705/how-to-assign-a-weight-to-a-term-query-in-lucene-solr)), that you can use `Query.setBoost()` but as I understand, it boosts all the terms equally in the query by the score specified, which is not what I want.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Query query1 = new TermQuery(new Term("your_default_field", "apple"));
query1.setBoost(0.2);

Query query2 = new TermQuery(new Term("your_default_field", "growers"));
query2.setBoost(0.7);

Query query3 = new TermQuery(new Term("your_default_field", "fruit"));
query3.setBoost(0.9);

Query query4 = new TermQuery(new Term("your_default_field", "ipad"));
query4.setBoost(0.05);

Query query5 = new TermQuery(new Term("your_default_field", "mac"));
query5.setBoost(0.06);

BooleanQuery combining = new BooleanQuery();
combining.add(query1, Occur.SHOULD);  
combining.add(query2, Occur.SHOULD);  // and so on and so forth
```

Comment: shouldn't 'Query combining = new BooleanQuery();' be 'BooleanQuery combining = new BooleanQuery();' ?

Answer (score 1):

another way that is much easier if the boosting scores are all positive.

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser( "content", new StandardAnalyzer() );
Query q = parser.parse( "Apple^1 juice^5 grower^4 mac^0.2 iphone^0.1 );

searcher.search( q, 10 );
```